# Can we solve a maximization problem using simplex algorithm without changing objective function?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I wonder if there could be some changes in the logistics of simplex method steps so as to use it for a maximization problem directly, i.e., till now we multiply the objective function by -1 and then treat it as a minimisation problem. I want a modified simplex to work on maximization directly. Now I think first change will be that instead of looking for negative coefficients in the cost vector, we will look for positive coefficients to choose an entering variable. I wonder what other changes need to be performed in the method? For eg some change in choosing a leaving variable step?

Comment: Just do exactly the same thing you would have done if you had originally multiplied the objective function by $-1$.

Comment: Hey, sorry I did not understand what you are trying to say. Can you kindly elaborate? @Hagen